# Offline flight simulator for Android phone

Tags: android, offline, flight-simulator

Is there a flight simulator that works offline (does not need internet in order to function)?

Including take-off, landing and missile evasion missions. (The missile evasion mission is optional.)

It should run on Android 2.3 and above.

Comment: Get some games from this [list](http://koolwap.in/games_applications_offline-flight-simulator-_apk.html)

Comment: The Guardians of the Sky game includes all of the things you want.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.threye.iaf.gots&hl=en

Comment: Then, why not post that as an answer?